# How can I duplicate and 'double view' my laptop desktop? Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

Basically I want to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I know it's weird/unusual thing but it's what I want. I don't care that half the screen gets cut off.

How can I do this on my windows 10 laptop? Thanks.

Comment: You want to show two of the same screen on a single screen on your laptop? Perhaps if you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish we'll have a better idea how best to help.

Comment: What you describe would require third-party software.  I am not aware of any software that does what you want.

Comment: Nothing native to show two identical screens on the same display. You can open apps and snap to side / top and have two or four app screens quite easily.  You can also run a second machine in VMware Workstation and run it in Unity Mode to use both (different) systems simultaneously

Comment: Hi @music2myear I am trying to stream my laptop screen into a VR headset. So I want to replicate the screen and ideally add some viewpoint distortion. I don't know if this is possible. I am also open to doing this with a Linux (ubuntu) laptop.

Comment: Do you want to duplicate the screen twice, or only move it over to the right? Do you care about what is displayed in the left half? Do you want to use the mouse in both halves?

Comment: If all you need is to stream your laptop screen to your VR, isn't it easier to duplicate the screen separately for each eye/lens? That way you also preserve the entire screen real estate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a solution for duplicating half of the screen and for both halves
to be functional.

The only solution I can think of is to use a magnifier that can be adjusted to
mirror the left half over the right half.

An example magnifier that is adaptable enough to more or less fulfill the requirement
is [Magnifixer](http://www.blacksunsoftware.com/screenmagnifier.html):

[image]

The above was created by dragging the magnified area to the upper-right corner of
the screen, then resizing it to cover half of the screen.
Finally, I moved the cursor to the top-left corner and set "Fixed location"
via the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to stop it following the cursor.

The only problem here is that Magnifixer insists on having white borders around
the area.

Answer (score 0):

See if [Virtual Desktop](https://www.vrdesktop.net/) helps. From what I understand, you want to view your screen on VR, so this should be able to help you. It's available on Steam [here](https://store.steampowered.com/app/382110/).